# Why can't you change a variable in a global/nonlocal/return statement in python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In javascript I'm used to being able to `var a=5` or `return a=5`
but in python if I try `global a=5` , `nonlocal a=5` or `return a=5` I get an error. Is there a reason behind why you can't or am I just doing something wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In some languages it is common practice to stick an assignment inside of another statement. For example,

```
if a = 1 { ... }
```

the Python developers decided this is a source of bugs since it is too close to

```
if a == 1:
```

Therefore, they banned the nesting of assignments inside of other statements. Since

```
global a
```

is a statement unto itself, an assignment inside of the statement is not allowed.